# MobilePush SendLog - Adding Contact Key

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I'm trying to utilize the MobilePush Send Log template in SFMC in the same respects as the email send log, in which I can add additional columns and set up AMPScript variables in the messages to populate the data.

Does the MobilePush Send Log work this way?

Comment: yes it does work the same way

Comment: @EazyE Thank you for confirming